# Adding wordpress menu to custom role

Tags: wordpress

I am adding a menu to wordpress using the following:

```
add_action('admin_menu','menu');

function menu(){
add_menu_page('Test Admin Panel','Test Admin Panel','TestAdmin','test-plugin'.'-  top-level','mnuTopLevel');
add_submenu_page( 'test-plugin'.'-top-level', 'Test Results', 'Test Results', 'TestAdmin', 'test-plugin'.'results', 'mnuResults' );
```

The menu is shown when logging in with the administrator role but not when logging in with a custom role (created with the User Role Editor).

Can you help me on this one please ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: So what is your requirement? Wants to show the menu to all or to someone only??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third argument of [add_menu_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) should be a [capability](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) of the user.

Comment: perfect answer ... for some reason I was using the role rather than the capability. Thanks Rrikesh